# Why the result of mysql request does not appear on the popup?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, add-on

I'm discovering web extension. From some examples, I try to display the result of a mysql query in the popup but it is the content of the php which appears in the popup. If I execute the php, I have the good answer, if I execute the html, I have the good answer. Can you tell me if I did a mistake  or if something is missing ?

manifest.json

```
 {   
   "manifest_version": 2,

   "name": "Click to execute",

   "description": "test extension",
   "version": "1.0",

   "icons": {
   "48": "icon.png"   },

   "permissions": [
       "webRequest",
       "webNavigation",
       "tabs", "<all_urls>"   ],

   "browser_action": {
       "default_icon": "icon.png",
       "default_popup": "popup.html"   }

}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
  <body style="width: 300px">
    <div id="clickme"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
var xhr;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE 8 and older
    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
var data = "";
xhr.open("GET", "select-post.php", true); 
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain");
xhr.send(null);
xhr.onreadystatechange = display_data;
function display_data() {
if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
  if (xhr.status == 200) {
    //alert(xhr.responseText);
    console.log("test1");
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
    console.log("test2");
    document.getElementById("clickme").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
   } else {
        alert('There was a problem with the request.');
   }
 }
}
```

select-post.php

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; 
$username="****";  
$password="**********";
$db_name="********"; 

$con=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password");
mysql_select_db("$db_name");

$sql = "select count(*) as count
from ******_posts p
inner join ******_postmeta m on m.post_id = p.ID
inner join ******_term_relationships r on r.object_id = p.ID
inner join ******_terms t on t.term_id = r.term_taxonomy_id
where m.meta_key = '_wpc_expires'
and date_format(from_unixtime(CONVERT(meta_value, SIGNED INTEGER)),'%Y-%m-%d') > current_date
and t.slug = '*************'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<p>".$row['count']."</p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: how do you load the html file? Do you have `http://` in your adressbar or `file://`?

Comment: with _" content of the php"_ you mean the actual php code as we see it here, right?

Comment: About the html file, I execute with http. About the content of the php, if I look at the firefox inspector, I see " <div id="clickme"  <!-- ?php $host="localhost"........ '%Y-%m-%d') --> current_date and t.slug = 'cafago-com'"; $result = mysql_query($sql); while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { echo "

".$row['count']."
"; } ?>

Comment: I tried with a more simple query and I had the same problem. By writing the answer before, I'm asking if the <?php is correctly read because in the inspector the part between < from <?-- and > from the query is in comment

Comment: try changing `select-post.php` to a full url like `http://localhost/anypath/select-post.php`

Comment: Why are you using the long-deprecated `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible, and then learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Comment: @jeff, thank you very much, I have the correct answer in the popup. I have to understand why I can use the short name in html but I have to use the long name with web extension... Because of the origin call I think

Comment: @ADyson, don't worry, I always work with pdo. In this case, it's only because I begin in web extension, I will update my code when it will run correctly, so now ;-)

Comment: @MisterFisher If you know that PDO will work then why not use it to begin with? Doing it this way just means you have to re-test your server-side code afterwards. So you "get it working", then you change it, and then have to verify its "working" status all over again. Many people have made the same comment to me when I've pointed this kind of thing out and always say they'll fix it later...I always say fix it now and save yourself the re-testing effort.

Comment: @ADyson OK, only PDO now